# How to collapse a div with reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using reactjs and bootstrap v 3.0 but I can't find any collapse class in there so I defined this in my scss. The problem is that the togglebutton does not work or the toggleevent is not triggered on the div:

```
 toggle(e) {
        console.log('testing e',e)
        if (e.target.class === 'collapse') {
            e.target.className = 'collapse.in'
        } else {
            e.target.className = 'collapse'
        }
    }
```

This is my button:

```
<button className="btn btn-block" onClick={() => {
               this.toggle.bind('demo')
               }}>
     Open/close
</button>
```

How can I change the className from collapse to collapse.in and viceversa?
Here is a code sample:[Codepen](http://codepen.io/gekkerkanniet/pen/XNjazM?editors=1111)

Comment: shouldn't this be `e.target.className = 'collapse in'`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your SCSS and your HTML is fine, the problem is in how you used React.

The open/closed state of your component should be represented with a property in `this.state`, and the `toggle()` function should simply toggle that property. The `render()` function, finally, should be responsible of setting the right CSS class on the `<div>` it renders.

Here's your [Codepen updated with my suggestions](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mOrBPb?editors=1111).

What I did:

- I defined an initial state in the component constructor: as you can see, I set the `open` property to `false` initially;
- I rewrote the `toggle()` method, using `this.setState()` to toggle the value of the `open` property;
- I modified the `render()` function generating the class name of the `<div>` depending on the state. If the component state is open, the class name will be `"collapse in"`, else it will be only `"collapse"`.

Comment: That is awesome, how/where do I change state to open when I get a change in props which trigger a render? I want to open the panel then.

Comment: If you want to open the panel using props instead of state, just use `this.props` in the `render()` function instead of `this.state`. Please note that in that case you don't need to set initial state in constructor and you don't need the `toggle()` method, because parent components are responsible of changing child components props.

Comment: I would like to use props and state. Do I need to read the props in the componentDidMount event? But that would only fire once during initialization?

Comment: Props are always available in `this.props`, everywhere in the component. I suggest you to read a tutorial on React. Props and state usage are the very basic of React, and from your comment it looks like you're confused on what they are and how they work.

Comment: I changed your codepen slightly to show you what I mean: http://codepen.io/gekkerkanniet/pen/oYzGmN?editors=1111. Now it does not close anymore.

Answer (score 4):

There is also a library called as "react-bootstrap" which allows the integration of react with bootstrap. They have a very simple example for making the collapsible div, i am sharing the code for this which i have changed according to what i wanted.

You can use this component anywhere inside your code. This will just return a button with collapsible div.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {Button, Collapse} from 'react-bootstrap'

class Test extends Component{
    state={ 
        open:false
       }

    render(){
      return(
        <div className= "container">
           <Button className="btn" onClick={!this.state.open}>
               Collapse Div
           </Button>

           <Collapse in={this.state.open}>
               <div>
                  <p>Content when the button is clicked</p>
               </div>
           </Collapse>
        </div>
        );
       }
}

export default Test
```

Answer (score -1):

There are very nice libraries for this, I wouldn't advice to re-inventing the wheel but use something like [react-collapsible](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-collapsible)
You will have lots of flexibility of styling it too.

Install like this : `npm i react-collapsible`

Then use like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import Collapsible from 'react-collapsible';

const YourComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Collapsible trigger='Open' triggerWhenOpen='Close'>
      <button className="btn btn-block" onClick={() => {this.toggle.bind('demo') }}>
        This button collapses
      </button>
    </Collapsible>
  );
};
export default YourComponent;
```