# Why is does the toggle function only work after double clicking? (Javascript, CSS)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dom

Following [this w3 guide to creating collapsible divs](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_collapsible.asp), but inside a React app. The cards I made only collapse after double clicking instead of single clicking. The only difference I can find is that I'm not using `<script>` and instead using `onClick={function}`.

Here's my code:

At top of Card component file:

```
function collapseElement() {
  var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
    coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      console.log(i);
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      var content = this.nextElementSibling;
      if (content.style.display === "block") {
        content.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        content.style.display = "block";
      }
    });
  }
}
```

In Card Component:

```
<div>
    <button type="button" className="collapsible" onClick={collapseElement}>
        <div className="collapsible-title">
          {props.title}
        </div>
    </button>

    <div className="content">
      {props.children}
    </div>

</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do not confuse the awful W3Schools with the W3C (who have the website w3.org)

Comment: It would be strongly advisable to try and do this in React, rather than trying to shoehorn in JavaScript code that you found on the internet.  At its simplest, the problem is because your `collapseElement` function doesn't actually collapse the element, it assigns a click handler to the element which, when clicked, will collapse it.  But the problem is much deeper than that, because even correcting this will still leave you with very non-React code in your React component which is likely to fail in a variety of ways.

Comment: This is a terrible approach to take when using React, a component update will blow away the local DOM changes. Do your state changes in the state and not in the DOM.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to collapse a div with reactjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40629319/how-to-collapse-a-div-with-reactjs)

Answer (score 0):

You've set up the button's `onClick` to run `collapseElement`, which then goes through a list of elements with the "collapsible" class, and adds another click-event-listener to them to do the collapsing.

Either just run that function that adds a new click listener to every item, or just split out the actual function that toggles the content, and give that as the `onClick` tag.